# Why is it that there are invalid "dt" values in physics simulations?

Tags: xna, physics

I'm utilising some of NeHe's spring code, and after getting some pretty weird results I eventually realised the source of my error - my "dt" value in my Update function; the value that everything is multiplied against to speed up/slow down the calculations, hopefully based on frame rate. For example:

```
public void Update(GameTime gt) {
   float dt = gt.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 160.0f;
   velocity += (force / mass) * dt;
   position += velocity * dt;
}
```

160.0f seems to work pretty well for the player's update function, but for my spring simulation I need a value of about 3000, or I end up with my springs located at (NaN,NaN) pretty much instantly.

Why do bad values for this cause everything to go so crazy? I thought it would just slow down or speed up my simulation but it seems to cause some weird cascading failure.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to link to NeHe's post on this: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/introduction_to_physical_simulations/18005/

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to provide a useful answer.  What is GameTime?  What values are getting passed in for dt (e.g., are they sane values)?  Why are you using milliseconds instead of seconds, and what are the 160 or 3000 values supposed to be doing?  Where are force and mass calculated?  A result of NaN could be a few different things, but nothing in that code looks suspicious.

Comment: Sorry, this is XNA. GameTime is the construct that XNA uses to store stuff like total time elapsed and time elapsed since last tick. I'll upload my code so this seems clearer... hold on a sec.

Comment: XNA project in VS2010 here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/695255/Grapple.zip

Comment: Like @seanmiddleditch pointed out, using milliseconds is a __BAD__ idea. first of all, if you use springs with Explicit Euler, a set of values for the stiffness constant: Kmax = 300 and Dtmax = 0.005. Usually playing with values higher than these yields a disastrous explosion of particles :). Do switch that integration method, preferably to Implicit Euler.. or at least a Verlet one.

Comment: Where does that division by `160.0f` come from? Usually you'll want to have a `dt` value in seconds.. so it should be `gt.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds * 0.001f`

Comment: 160.f was just a value that made my player movement seem OK. 3000 was a value that made the springs not explode.

Comment: Again, do remember that a measureless/scalar value for Dt should be quite low. The rule of thumb is: the stiffer your springs, higher the forces, the lower the Dt should be. A denominator of 3000 transforms your milliseconds in thirds of a second. Assuming 60 fps, that would mean 16 milliseconds a timestep, then that is translated to a Dt of 16/3000 which means Dt = 0.00533, so close to what I suggested initially. Euler __needs__ a small timestep to be both accurate and stable. Use another method!

Comment: 160.f makes it seem ok because it's not a slow motion simulation, but for such high timesteps, you _need_ an __implicit__ method. Sorry, but that's what those "real time" cloth simulators, soft body engines really use. Otherwise, stick to Verlet and tune its parameters until satisfied. A mass spring system shouldn't cause many problems with Verlet (many of the people here have used that)

Answer (score 3):

When you do `position += velocity * dt` you use the new value of `velocity` while a more accurate calculation should be using the **average** value for the whole elapsed frame duration. See [this article I wrote](http://lol.zoy.org/blog/2011/12/14/understanding-motion-in-games) about how this affects trajectory computation.

In your specific case, if `force` is a constant, using Verlet integration will give you the exact trajectory whatever the framerate. If Verlet integration is still not enough, because for instance you introduce friction, you can use a higher order integration method such as 4th order Runge-Kutta.

Comment: Force is a constant; it's basically the total of all the forces that act on an Entity between frames.

I've updated my Update function but I still get an "exploding" spring. Am I missing something?

`public virtual void Update(GameTime gt)

        {

            float dt = (float)gt.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 160.0f;

            Vector2 oldVelocity = velocity;

            velocity += (force / mass) * dt;

            position += (oldVelocity + velocity) * 0.5f * dt;

        }`

Comment: Well if `force` changes at each frame it's no longer a constant :-) I believe you are experiencing instability because `force` depends on the updated velocities of other entities. You could try to reduce `dt` in the physics step by performing several iterations of the whole physics code (including entity updates) during a single frame.

Comment: hey @Sam, very glad I read that article. I came across the same issue [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/why-is-my-velocity-decaying/13186#13186). Basicallly what I did was `position += velocity * dt + acceleration * 0.5 * dt * dt; velocity += acceleration * dt;` which is what you explain in your article. Its great to see someone bringing back some sanity into this issue, as I came across a lot of people too, who just repeated that flawed integration steps they read in the internet like a mantra without really thinking about it. So thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's Explicit Euler Integration, the easiest and dumbest integrator ever. It's prone to explode your simulation if Dt is either variable or large.
What you could do is to switch to another one:

[Verlet/Velocity Verlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration)

[Midpoint Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method

[Implicit Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method)
http://www.physics.udel.edu/~jim/Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations/The%20Implicit%20Euler%20Method.pdf

[Predictor Corrector methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictor%E2%80%93corrector_method)

[Runge Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Why use them (another [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25300/why-use-runge-kutta-integration-over-improved-euler-integration) post)
These are a bit better, but not as easy to implement. 
You also might want to look at [adaptive timestep methods](http://www.math.ku.edu/~huang/research/paper/HL97.pdf).. which are quite related to your problem (e.g. variable frame-rate might induce jittery simulations).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `gt.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds` then you should be using `gt.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds`. Not sure if that have some influence here, but it's a potential bug.

To increase precision (if that is the problem) you could switch to [ElapsedGameTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) which is 100-ns intervals, and to double for fp intermediate calculations and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your timestep should be calulcated as:

```
float dt = gt.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 1000.0f;
```

Since you want dt to be the delta time in seconds (so a dt of 1.0 would mean that 1 second passed).

If that doesn't work, then it's likely that the timer you are using to calculate ElapsedGameTime isn't accurate enough (a common problem with millisecond timers on Windows, which has a resolution of 16ms).

If the value of gt.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds is constantly 0 or 16 then you need a more precise timer.